# Ionic2 - 'this' is undefined in custom form validator

Tags: javascript, validation, angular, asynchronous, ionic2

I'm building an app using the Ionic2 framework. I have a form that asks the user for an email address. I have built a custom async Validator for that form which hits my API's endpoint to check to see if the given email address is already in use.

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class SignUpValidator {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  validateEmail(control: FormControl): any {

    console.log("this, in validateEmail: " + this);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post('localhost:3000/api/registration/checkemail', {email: control.value})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            if (data.emailInUse) {
              resolve({
                "email in use": true
              });
            }
            else {
              resolve(null);
            }
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
          }
        );

    });
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when the validation runs:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
```

Obviously, 'this' is undefined, but I want to know why. When I simply navigate to the page in which my form lives, it seems that the validator function is called three times before the user even inputs any information into the form. What's more, 'this' is defined in the first two calls to my validator, but in undefined in the third and subsequent calls.

The console output, as soon as the page is navigated to, looks like this:

```
this, in validateEmail: [object Object]  sign-up.validator.ts:49

this, in validateEmail: [object Object]  sign-up.validator.ts:49

this, in validateEmail: undefined        sign-up.validator.ts:49
```

The Component that calls this validator looks like this:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Slides, ToastController, Checkbox, App} from 'ionic-angular';
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import {SignUpValidator} from "./sign-up.validator";
import {AuthService} from "../../services/auth.service";
import {AccountCreationService} from "../../services/account-creation.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-sign-up',
  templateUrl: 'sign-up.html',
  providers: [AuthService, AccountCreationService, SignUpValidator]
})

export class SignUpPage {

  @ViewChild('signupSlider') slider: Slides;
  @ViewChild('individual') individual: Checkbox;
  @ViewChild('business') business: Checkbox;

  private formPersonalInformation: FormGroup;
  private formLoginInformation: FormGroup;
  private formCreditCardInformation: FormGroup;

  private checkboxPro: string;
  private checkboxConsumer: string;
  private businessType: string;
  private fullName: string;
  private DOB: string;
  private addressLine1: string;
  private addressLine2: string;
  private state: string;
  private city: string;
  private zipCode: number;
  private country: string;
  private email: string;
  private password1: string;
  private password2: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private authService: AuthService,
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder, private toastCtrl: ToastController,
              private app: App, private accountCreationService: AccountCreationService,
              private signUpValidator: SignUpValidator) {

    this.formLoginInformation = formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(45), Validators.pattern('[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,}')]), signUpValidator.validateEmail],
      password1: ['', Validators.required],
      password2: ['', Validators.required],
      checkboxPro: [null],
      checkboxConsumer: [null]
    });

...
```

Why is my validator called three times before the form is even touched, and why does 'this' disappear?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am facing the exact same problem.